# Self-Signed SSL: Subject Alternative Name (SAN) are not respected by my web browsers

Tags: ssl, self-signed-certificate

I have created a self-signed certificate that works with `https://*.blah.com` (for example www.blah.com works). I have `blah.com` listed as a SAN but `https://blah.com` doesn't work with my web browser.

What's wrong with my cert?

Here's a screenshot of the error:

[image]

Comment: how to actually added the SAN on the existing certificate? Or need to reissue back the CSR private key before we generate the certificate.

Answer (score 3):

I don't think you added the SAN value properly to your cert. It's not just a string field in the Subject.  It's a separate extension that would be listed further down in the cert details like this:
[image]

Additionally as Rob-d mentioned, the error message the browser gave you is basically telling you that your Common Name (CN) field is invalid (probably because you tried to add an invalid field to the Subject called "Subject Alternative Name").

Answer (score 0):

the error says it has a problem with the common name and not the SAN, the common name is * - this is a wildcard certificate, also you would not need to name any subject alternative names when using a wildcard cert.